# ERROR : more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

ER Diagram :

[image]

Question :
Add new items to the stock in case of absence if the number of sales of that product is above
the 20% of all sales combined, to make sure it does not run out of stock.

I've tried :

```
UPDATE products SET current_stock=
(SELECT p.current_stock FROM sales 
INNER JOIN products AS p ON product_id=p.id
WHERE sold_count=(SELECT sold_count FROM sales
WHERE sold_count < sold_count * sold_count * 0.2 )) + 1;
```

But I had this ERROR message :

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Give an alias to the first products table, as in `UPDATE products p1 ...` and use it in the condition. Otherwise, your query is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
UPDATE products SET current_stock = current_stock + 1
WHERE id = (SELECT p.id FROM sales 
INNER JOIN products AS p ON product_id=p.id
WHERE sold_count < sold_count * sold_count * 0.2
GROUP BY p.id);
```

I had to use WHERE p.id = ...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update `current_stock` with a subquery, so the subquery must return **ONE** row, **ONE** column (**ONE** value).

Your query returns more than one row - probably here:

```
SELECT sold_count 
FROM sales
WHERE sold_count < sold_count * sold_count * 0.2
```

Because you are querying every `sold_count` that is lower than something... you could have millions...

When you update from a subquery you have to make sure that the result of the query is just one value.

Answer (score 0):

Operators like <,=,>,... expect a scalar result to be returned from the subquery. If it returns multiple, it's like comparing an apple to an array of oranges.

I don't totally understand the question, is this what you are trying to do?

```
UPDATE products
  FROM ( SELECT S.product_id,
                CASE WHEN S.sold_count >= SUM(S.sold_count) OVER() THEN P.current_stock + 1
                     ELSE P.current_stock
                 END adjusted_Stock
           FROM sales S
          INNER 
           JOIN product P 
             ON S.product_id = P.id
       ) AS UPDT
   SET current_stock = UPDT.adjusted_Stock
 WHERE id = UPDT.product_id;
```